# request rate limiting per resource in a rest api per user (subscription) in wso2 api manager (3.2.0)

Tags: request, wso2, token, limit, wso2-api-manager

in wso2 api manager (3.2.0) :

1. Defined a rest api in publisher
2. Defined a resource
3. Then customer subscribed and send request to defined resource by generated token from wso2

Now, I want to limit the request rate for each resource per user, for example, by imposing restrictions on tokens. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve per user rate limiting, you need to write a custom rate limiting policy.

Go to the admin portal,  **Rate Limiting Policies -> Custom Policies** and add a custom policy you want.

1. The following is an example of a custom rate-limiting policy for API level, defining a limit of 5 requests per minute for the admin user.

   Name:    **CustomPolicy** 
   Description: **Sample custom policy**. 
   Key Template:    **$userId:$apiContext:$apiVersion**

Siddhi query:

```
FROM RequestStream
SELECT userId, ( userId == 'admin@carbon.super'  and apiContext == '/pizzashack/1.0.0' and apiVersion == '1.0.0') AS isEligible ,
str:concat('admin@carbon.super',':','/pizzashack/1.0.0:1.0.0') as throttleKey
INSERT INTO EligibilityStream;
FROM EligibilityStream [isEligible==true] #throttler:timeBatch(1 min)
SELECT throttleKey, (count(throttleKey) >= 5) as isThrottled, expiryTimeStamp group by throttleKey
INSERT ALL EVENTS into ResultStream;
```

2. To write a resource level custom throttling, follow the below example.

   Key Template: **$userId:$resourceKey**

Siddhi query:

```
FROM RequestStream
SELECT userId, ( userId == 'admin@carbon.super'  and resourceKey == '/pizzashack/1.0.0/1.0.0/*:GET') AS isEligible ,
str:concat('admin@carbon.super',':',resourceKey) as throttleKey
INSERT INTO EligibilityStream;
FROM EligibilityStream [isEligible==true] #throttler:timeBatch(1 min)
SELECT throttleKey, (count(throttleKey) >= 5) as isThrottled, expiryTimeStamp group by throttleKey
INSERT ALL EVENTS into ResultStream;
```

You can refer the documentation[1] for the further reference.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/rate-limiting/advanced-topics/custom-throttling/

Comment: thanks , how to apply it ? and another question how to change this to apply per resource?

Comment: When you create the custom policy in the admin portal, it will automatically applies.
I modified the answer by adding a resource level example as well.

Comment: when you define the resource , you determine rate limiting policy (for example unlimited ,10k per minute and ... ) .this custom policy have priority over this rate limitng policy or no and what I must choose this rate limiting policy in resource defintion? @chashikajw

Comment: Both applies. Small limit hits first. If you want, you can define custom subscription policies as well and attach to the API. (You can choose to apply those in API level or resource level). Then choose them when creating the application. Those are application level tiers.

Comment: how to check logs or anywhere that this policy being affected to specific api resource ?